# Converting CSV to dictionary of dictionaries, avoiding for/while loops

Tags: python, csv

I was wondering if it was possible to convert a `CSV` into a nested dictionary without having to use any loop.

I am using `Dictreader` (which is great), but I need to use a loop to assign each key to the result of each `Dictreader` element.

Below is a simple example of data that I have in a `CSV` file:

```
Open time,Open,High,Low,Close
1590994800000,0.07863,0.07896,0.07863,0.07874
1590994860000,0.07874,0.07875,0.07855,0.07870
1590994920000,0.07868,0.07892,0.07868,0.07887
```

The output of `Dictreader` would be:

```py
[
    {
        "Open time": "1590994800000",
        "Open": "0.07863",
        "High": "0.07896",
        "Low": "0.07863",
        "Close": "0.07874",
    },
    {
        "Open time": "1590994860000",
        "Open": "0.07874",
        "High": "0.07875",
        "Low": "0.07855",
        "Close": "0.07870",
    },
    {
        "Open time": "1590994920000",
        "Open": "0.07868",
        "High": "0.07892",
        "Low": "0.07868",
        "Close": "0.07887",
    },
]
```

I was wondering if it was possible to get such output without using a `for`/`while` loop:

```py
{
    "1590994800000": {
        "Open time": "1590994800000",
        "Open": "0.07863",
        "High": "0.07896",
        "Low": "0.07863",
        "Close ": "0.07874",
    },
    "1590994860000": {
        "Open time": "1590994860000",
        "Open": "0.07874",
        "High": "0.07875",
        "Low": "0.07855",
        "Close": "0.07870",
    },
    "1590994920000": {
        "Open time": "1590994920000",
        "Open": "0.07868",
        "High": "0.07892",
        "Low": "0.07868",
        "Close": "0.07887",
    },
}
```

I would also be happy getting something like this:

```py
{
    "1590994800000": {"0.07863", "0.07896", "0.07863", "0.07874"},
    "1590994860000": {"0.07874", "0.07875", "0.07855", "0.07870"},
    "1590994920000": {"0.07868", "0.07892", "0.07868", "0.07887"},
}
```

Is there some variant of `csv.reader` or `csv.Dictreader` that would let me get such output?

Comment: If you're going to be doing something repeatedly, your only options are loops or repeating code (arguably you could cobble something together with recursion, but that would just be to make a point) - why are you trying to avoid using loops for something that lends itself perfectly to loops?

Answer (score -1):

You will need a `for` to iterate over the contents of the `csv.DictReader`, but there's no need to iterate over each individual key in each dictionary.  Do:

```
{row['Open time']: row for row in csv.DictReader(...)}
```